# Can you use "this" attribute on onclick of an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Can you use the `this` tag for the onclick on an HTML tag?
Here's my JS code...

```
function changeImage() {
    this/*<-- right there <--*/.src=a;
}
document.getElementsByTagName('img').onclick = function(){ 
    changeImage();
} ;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: dont need the wrapper; just use `document.getElementsByTagName('img').onclick = changeImage;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method to invoke the function with the context of `this`.

In this case, you would use:

```
changeImage.call(this)
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ncz2gq/)

```
function changeImage() {
    this.src = 'http://placehold.it/200/f00';
}
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onclick = function(){ 
    changeImage.call(this);
};
```

As a side note, [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements. You need to apply the `onclick` handler to an element within that collection.

If you want to apply the event listener to the collection of elements, you iterate through them and add event listeners like this:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbq9fx5h/)

```
function changeImage() {
    this.src = 'http://placehold.it/200/f00';
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), function(el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('click', changeImage);
});
```

Or you could simplify it:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6r9mhnun/)

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), function(el, i) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.src = 'http://placehold.it/200/f00';
    });
});
```

Comment: but how do i set the image? the variable `a` is the source needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use it this way...

```
function changeImage(curr) {
    console.log(curr.src);
}
document.getElementsByTagName('img').onclick = function(){ 
    changeImage(this);
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things wrong.

1. You are assigning the event handler to a **NodeList** instead of to an element (or set of elements)
2. You are calling `changeImage` without any context (so `this` will be `undefined` or `window` depending on if you are in strict mode or now).

A fixed version would look like this:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function () {
        changeImage.call(this);
    };
}
```

But a tidier version would skip the anonymous function that does nothing except call another function:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = changeImage;
}
```

And modern code would use `addEventListener`.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener('click', changeImage);
}
```

However, images are not interactive controls. You can't (by default) focus them, so this approach would make them inaccessible to people who didn't use a pointing device. Better to use controls that are designed for interaction in the first place.

Generally, this should be a plain button. You can use CSS to remove the default padding / border / background.

If you can't put a button in your plain HTML, you can add it with JS.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = "button";
    image.parentNode.replaceChild(button, image);
    button.appendChild(image);
    button.addEventListener('click', changeImage);
}

function changeImage(event) {
    this.firstChild.src = a;
}
```